# Custom form validation in django-inspectional-registration

Tags: python, django

I'm using django-inspectional-registration module for django.
My question is how to validate even default emails in this module.
I have tried to inherit from `RegistrationForm` and edit text in `raise ValidationError(_("The two email fields didn't match."))` in `clean(self)` method:

```
from registration.forms import RegistrationForm
from registration.views import RegistrationView
from django.forms import ValidationError
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class MyRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):

   def clean(self):
        if 'email1' in self.cleaned_data and 'email2' in self.cleaned_data:
            if self.cleaned_data['email1'] != self.cleaned_data['email2']:
                raise ValidationError(_(
                    "My text"))
        return self.cleaned_data
```

Also I have changed urls:

```
url(r'^registration/register/$', RegistrationView.as_view(), {'form_class': MyRegistrationForm}, name='registration_register'),
url(r'^registration/', include('registration.urls')),
```

But in form when I put two different emails it still shows error with the text `The two email fields didn't match.`

UPD. Now I see that django-inspectional-registration doesn't have argument in view to pass MyRegistrationForm like django-registration.

Comment: What do you mean by validating default emails?

Comment: I want them to be on gmail only

Comment: Do you mean user can register only using gmail account?

Comment: Yes, I wanted them to use only gmail accounts.